# Alternate values in a range of cells using Openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to alternate a value in an excel range using openpyxl with a loop, for example starting a "x" value in ['A1'] or (1,1), and the next loop moving to (2,2) etc etc until getting to column 8 or H, and row 10.

Comment: You should always include the code that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to loop like (1,1), (2,2) ...(8,8) [looping upto H column] here is the solution. If you need to increase the cells then change the max_value of range to your required number.

Using **openpyxl-cell** module:

```
import openpyxl
import os


def func():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sample.xlsx'))
    ws = wb['Sheet1']
    for var in range(1, 9):
        print(ws.cell(row=var, column=var).value)


func()
```

**Input**: (snapshot from excel)

[image]

**Output**: (Snapshot from IDE):

[image]